# Google App Engine Tutorial example not working

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-datastore

I deployed the Web Application "Google App Engine Tutorial example 1" (http://googcloudlabs.appspot.com/codelabexercise1.html) to GAE at the site http://templiba.appspot.com . I can access the site but the application is not saving the Product and Item values in the DataStore. The same is happening when I try on my local. It there a known fix for it? Or could you assist me with a Tutorial example with code that writes to the DataStore? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you made all the required modifications to the code provided as outlined in Step 4? When I migrated from Google App Engine for Python to Java, the Getting Started guide was very useful; it covers all the basic concepts starting from creating the Eclipse project while presenting the code in a easier way to understand (in my opinion) than the Code Labs which seem slighly outdated (broken links, etc).

- [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/)
- [Datastore Overview within Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore)